# Can a QAbstractItemModel trigger a layout change whenever underyling data is changed?

Tags: python, architecture, pyqt, pyqt5

The following is a slightly modified version of the [Model/View To-Do List tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/modelview-architecture/).

I have a class `Heard` that is composed of a list of `Animal`. The `Heard` serves as the underlying data for a `HeardModel` which is displayed in a `ListView` in my interface.

In my `MainWindow`, I've created a function called `add_animal_to_heard` which:

1. Creates a new `Animal` using the user input
2. Uses the `Heard` class's `add_animal` method to add the new `Animal` to the `Heard`
3. Tells the `HeardModel` to update the view using `layoutChanged.emit()`

It's this last point that concerns me. To manage increasing complexity in the app, shouldn't the `HeardModel` know to trigger a layout change **whenever the underlying `Heard` data is changed?** Is this possible, and if so, is there any reason that wouldn't be desireable?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from typing import Dict, List

qt_creator_file = "animals.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qt_creator_file)


class Animal:

    def __init__(self, genus: str, species: str):
        self.genus = genus
        self.species = species

    def name(self):
        return f"{self.genus} {self.species}"


class Heard:
    animals: List[Animal]

    def __init__(self, animals: List[Animal]):
        self.animals = animals

    def add_animal(self, animal: Animal):
        self.animals.append(animal)

    def remove_animal(self, animal: Animal):
        self.animals.remove(animal)


class HeardModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    heard: Heard

    def __init__(self, *args, heard: Heard, **kwargs):
        super(HeardModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.heard = heard

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            animal = self.heard.animals[index.row()]
            return animal.name()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.heard.animals)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = HeardModel(heard=Heard([Animal('Canis', 'Familiaris'), Animal('Ursus', 'Horribilis')]))
        self.heardView.setModel(self.model)

        self.addButton.pressed.connect(self.add_animal_to_heard)

    def add_animal_to_heard(self):
        genus = self.genusEdit.text()
        species = self.speciesEdit.text()
        if genus and species:  # Don't add empty strings.
            # Create new animal
            new_animal = Animal(genus, species)

            # Add animal to heard
            self.model.heard.add_animal(new_animal)

            # Trigger refresh.
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

            # Empty the input
            self.genusEdit.setText("")
            self.speciesEdit.setText("")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Heard` object (maybe you meant "Herd"?) has no direct relation with the model unless you make it so.

You have to create a "link" between them, which can be done in various ways depending on your needs.

Note that the *proper* way to deal with changes in the data (and model) size is not to use `layoutChanged` but to use the insert/remove functions of QAbstractItemModel: [`beginInsertRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) (which must end with an `endInsertRows()`) and [`beginRemoveRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginRemoveRows) (then, `endRemoveRows()`). This is extremely important because using these functions ensures that the view can keep a list of persistent indexes during the change, allowing proper functionality: selections are correctly handled, the view update is optimized, and possible item editors will be still associated with the correct indexes.

It is also better to let the model handle its behavior and not do that externally: this is also valid for signals, which should be emitted within the model class. While it technically doesn't change the result, it is more correct the point of view of object structure and code maintenance (see ["Separation of concerns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

Anyhow, the most common way to do all this is to let the model handle insertion and removal of items in the underlying data structure:

```py
class HeardModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    # ...
    def add_animal(self, animal):
        row = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.heard.add_animal(animal)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def remove_animal(self, animal):
        try:
            row = self.heard.animals.index(animal)
            self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
            self.heard.remove_animal(animal)
            self.endRemoveRows()
        except ValueError:
            print(f'animal {animal.name} not in model')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    # ...
    def add_animal_to_heard(self):
        genus = self.genusEdit.text()
        species = self.speciesEdit.text()
        if genus and species:  # Don't add empty strings.
            self.model.add_animal(Animal(genus, species))
            self.genusEdit.clear()
            self.speciesEdit.clear()
```

Note that this is not the only way to achieve the wanted result.

For instance, you could create a reference of the model in the `Heard` object and then implement the above within their respective functions.

In that case, you could implement [`insertRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) and [`removeRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRows), so that you can just call `insertRow()` inside `add_animal()` in the `Heard` object as long as the model reference exists (and it's a QAbstractItemModel instance).
Still, as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing) (including that of [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing)), the related begin/end functions must be implemented anyway.

In any case, it's extremely important that the handling of both model and data structure uses a *unique* interface, otherwise you will risk unexpected results or fatal crash: for instance, if you try to remove an animal from the `animals` list without properly notifying the model, its `data()` function will raise an `IndexError`.
This aspect must not be underestimated, especially considering the possible "increasing complexity in the app" as you yourself noted; imagine adding a new feature to the program or fixing a newly found bug, months after you last opened the project: not only it's quite easy to *forget* some aspects of the implementation after some time has passed since they have been established, but it may be painfully hard to understand again what the code did (and why or how) or even find the cause of possible further bugs introduced by the new modifications.

That said, since it doesn't seem like the `Heard` object implements lots of functions, you could simplify everything by merging it with the model and use a single class instead:

```py
class HeardModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, animals):
        super().__init__()
        self.animals = animals
```

You could even do a further step more and *actually* merge them using multiple inheritance:

```py
class Heard:
    animals: List[Animal]

    def __init__(self, animals):
        super().__init__() # important!
        self.animals = animals

    # etc...


# note: the inheritance order is important
class HeardModel(Heard, QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    # no __init__ override required unless it needs other operations

    def add_animal(self, animal):
        row = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        super().add_animal(animal)
        self.endInsertRows()

    # etc...


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = HeardModel([
            Animal('Canis', 'Familiaris'), 
            Animal('Ursus', 'Horribilis')
        ])
        # etc...
```

Comment: Thank you for a tremendously helpful answer. This not only answered my direct question, but also provided good advice on best practices. If I understand correctly, the best way to go about handling behaviour is to do ALL adding/removing through the `HeardModel` (and yes I did indeed mean "Herd", my bad!)

Comment: @AndrewPlowright You're welcome! Yes, the concept may be familiar if you know about the [Zen of Python](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python): "There should be one– and preferably only one –obvious way to do it"; a Qt program is isually a *Qt centered* program, and Qt is quite strict about the separation of concerns (for good reasons, I'd add) in its OOP paradigm. While you could obviously do it any way you want, the extreme modularity of Qt classes expects that whatever directly concerns the structure and behavior of object X should be done *within* X, through its unique interfaces/APIs.